# Eclipse 3.5.2 Does Not Hit Breakpoints when Remote Debugging on Tomcat 6»

Tags: scala, tomcat, breakpoints, remote-debugging

This is a local-to-local debug setup, from an Eclipse instance to Tomcat on localhost.

I've tried starting tomcat from both `/etc/init.d/tomcat6 start` and from `/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/catalina.sh jpda start` (ie from the startup command and from `CATALINA_HOME` command), no change in result.

The `JAVA_OPTS` to Tomcat are

> JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true
>   -Xmx256m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8888,server=y,suspend=n"

Eclipse project is a simple Scala Lift (2.8.1/2.3) web project generated from the default Lift Maven archetype (this has worked in debug before, so it's not the archetype's fault).

Eclipse Remote Debugging  configuration is default, except port changed to `8888`. Source path includes project directory.

Maven is used for build/deploy, so a `mvn clean` and `mvn tomcat:redeploy` is done after breakpoints are set.

Remote Debug session is launched, connects to Tomcat as seen in screenshot.[image: eclipse connected to tomcat debug port]

Tomcat does seem to be in debug mode, as evidenced by catalina.out:

> 16:19:37.865 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1]
>   DEBUG comet_trace - AJAX Request:
>   C8436967E450AD62D37654BBB3B5FCB9
>   Map(F27626326198LU12KZ -> List(foo), q
>   -> List(f0), limit -> List(10), timestamp -> List(1306271977857))
>
> 16:19:37.866 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1]
>   DEBUG comet_trace - AJAX Response:
>   C8436967E450AD62D37654BBB3B5FCB9
>   PlainTextResponse(,List(),200)
>
> 16:19:37.870 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1]
>   INFO  net.liftweb.util.TimeHelpers -
>   Service request (GET)
>   /bsa2/search/ajax_request returned
>   200, took 11 Milliseconds
>
> 16:19:44.312 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] DEBUG
>   comet_trace - AJAX Request:
>   C8436967E450AD62D37654BBB3B5FCB9
>   Map(F27626326198LU12KZ -> List(foo), q
>   -> List(), limit -> List(10), timestamp -> List(1306271984133))

Web site is accessed with browser on the normal Tomcat URL (eg `http://localhost:8080/test/cleanproject`).

No breakpoint is ever reached.

Comment: I can see that you are using Scala, so the problem might be specific to Scala plugin and not to Eclipse and Java in general. Usually, when I hit such problem (breakpoints not hit), it almost always means that either my sources are different from the runtime or that the runtime runs classes without debug, so you cannot hit a breakpoint based on a line, only breakpoints for method entry/exit.

Comment: I've pretty much come to the same conclusion, it's the one area that I haven't traced through yet. For method entry/exit, I do have breakpoints set on the method def line--shouldn't those be hit even without deployed runtime debug info?

Comment: It's reasonable enough to expect this, but I've got no experience with Scala to confirm this. I'll suggest that you add tag 'scala', so the question receives the deserved attention from the Scala guys as well.

Comment: I have had problems with debugging and Tomcat.  You could give jetty (http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) a try--it works great!

Comment: Eventually gave up and took the advice to just run Jetty. In the wet winter earth, a a small crack appears in a nut hidden by a squirrel.